# Android: default AppTheme background colors

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

What are the **default background colors** for Activities in Android's AppTheme style?

I'm looking for the hex code, or something that I can reference. It should be one for the LIGHT theme and one for the DARK theme.

Or where can I look them up? I'm confused by all the files and can't find the place where they actually say the color.

Thanks for your help.

**Update:**

I found entries in the SDK in `/data/values/colors.xml`, which are referenced by

```
@android:color/background_holo_light
@android:color/background_holo_dark
```

But I cannot put them as background color of my Views: it is giving an error saying the values are not public. Is there a workaround?

Comment: On Eclipse, use [Ctrl-Space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19725739/632951).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check out this [colors.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml) file. If you do a Ctrl-F for `"backround_holo_dark"` you can find the hex code. All the other holo theme colors are there as well. Enjoy!

```
<drawable name="screen_background_holo_light">#fff3f3f3</drawable>
<drawable name="screen_background_holo_dark">#ff000000</drawable>
<color name="background_holo_dark">#ff000000</color>
<color name="background_holo_light">#fff3f3f3</color>
```

Comment: And how can I reference it? I tried `@android:color/background_holo_light` but the XML shows me an error saying this value is not public.

Comment: @Terry like you stated, it is not public so unfortunately you cannot reference it directly. What I have done in the past is to just copy the values you need to your resource directory and reference them from there. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12657367/2660435) suggests the same thing.

Comment: these are not valid hex color values

Comment: @maracuja-juice those are [argb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) values.

Answer (score 153):

You can use your theme's default background color by referencing the attribute:

`?android:colorBackground`

Comment: How do you set this programmatically?

Comment: mMainContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));