# No Colors.xml file in Android project

Tags: android, xml, colors

I was looking at the [following Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841640/android-default-apptheme-background-colors) in a attempt to change my layout's background color. It said to go add a new color in the "colors.xml" file located at res\values\colors.xml I went to that directory but there was no colors.xml file. Where can I find the colors.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on res->values folder and make a new file named colors.xml and define your color as following in colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
</resources>
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make one of your own. There is no colors.xml initially.

Comment: Depends on ide. Android studio creates it initially

Comment: I'm using Android studio and it did not create it initially.

Comment: I think it might create it if you choose some special template. Otherwise you should make it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If your Android project lacks a `colors.xml` file, you can create a new file at:

```
res\values\
```

Name the new file `colors.xml` and populate it as needed for your purposes.