# Error with Uploading APK to Google Play

Tags: android, xml, google-play, android-manifest, apk

Upload failed:

```
Your APK cannot be analyzed using 'aapt dump badging'. Error output:
to run aapt dump badging:
W/ResourceType(12713): Bad XML block: header size 28024 or total size 1702240364 is     larger than data size 3783
ERROR: AndroidManifest.xml is corrupt
```

This is the error I am getting when I attempt to upload an APK onto Google Play and am completely unsure of what to do. I have looked at other posts but am unable to fix my problem. Any help is appreciated!!

-- Moksh

Comment: see this link may it help.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706704/android-app-development-error-bad-xml-block-header-size-60-or-total-size-3932

Comment: @Moksh did, you find a solution. I'm facing exactly the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Is your apk run on emulator or device..?
Clean and build your project again. Sign it with your very own keystore and then try to upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure following points are need to be taken care of while uploading file on android market

- `"android:versionCode"` attribute from `AndroidManifest.xml` is proper.
- `"android:versionName"` attribute from `AndroidManifest.xml` is proper.
- The package name is very unique,. Because all the apps on android market are separated by the package.